# Apex class generation

Tags: wsdl

Anyone please help me to create apex class from this wsdl file.[wsdl file here.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL)

Thank You.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: I want to generate apex class from this wsdl file, after that i'll get response from wsdl apex class.

Answer (score 2):

There are many [restrictions on what WSDL can be handled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) by the Apex tooling including:

> WSDL files with mulitple portTypes, multiple services, or multiple
>   bindings

so after removing those elements from your xml here is the correct WSDL. save this code as xml and try to import.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
      <s:element name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Fahrenheit" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FahrenheitToCelsiusResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Celsius" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CelsiusToFahrenheitResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:FahrenheitToCelsius" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheit" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="Fahrenheit" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="FahrenheitToCelsiusHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="Celsius" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CelsiusToFahrenheitHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="TempConvertSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:FahrenheitToCelsiusSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CelsiusToFahrenheitSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="TempConvertSoap" type="tns:TempConvertSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="FahrenheitToCelsius">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/FahrenheitToCelsius" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="CelsiusToFahrenheit">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="TempConvert">
    <wsdl:port name="TempConvertSoap" binding="tns:TempConvertSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>


  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

you will have to learn more about the [elements in a WSDL file](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) than you probably want to before attempting that.

Comment: Sir, it get parsing but apex class generation is failed.

Comment: Apex Generation Failed  Unable to find soap 1.1 address

Comment: that error is coming because Apex support only soap 1.1 and you are using soap 1.2 version of wsdl so you need to remove the reference of soap 1.2 please check update xml.

Answer (score -1):

In `Salesforce Setup`, in `Develop > Apex Classes`, you have a button `Generate from a WSDL`.

Then choose your file and you will have your APEX class.

Comment: Yes sir, i known but it shows lot errors that's why i ask help for this.

Comment: Ok, so update your post with errors you get.